# Margins and paddings between elements in LibGDX

Tags: android, layout, libgdx

I have a `VerticalGroup` of `Button`s on my screen. The problem is that buttons located very closely one to one. I want to add some spaces between buttons, something like padding or margin. I find `pad` method in `Table` in API, but `VerticalGroup` doesn't extends Table and therefore doesn't contain this method. Please point me how I can add some spacing between buttons inside `VerticalGroup`

Sample code

```
VerticalGroup buttons = new VerticalGroup();
buttons.addActor(btn1);
buttons.addActor(bnt2);
// ... and so on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding padding from the parent (the `VerticalGroup`) add the padding to each element (the `Button`s).

A libGDX [Button](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html) is also a [Table](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/tablelayout/Table.html) and Tables support various [pad](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/tablelayout/Table.html#pad%28int%29) methods.  Those are documented to change the padding around the outside of the table (or button in your case).

Comment: I tried to do this, but this is has not any effect. As I understand pad setups padding inside the table. But in this case I need to setup padding outside

Comment: Links are all dead.

Answer (score 15):

Better late than never: libGDX uses TableLayout (https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout) to order the widgets. When you follow the link and you go to the 'Padding' section, you will have an image illustrating your situation. In order to get the margin (the spacing **outside** of the button) you have to use the following code:

```
 table.add(button).width(100).pad(10);
 table.row();
 table.add(lastButton);
```

Answer (score 14):

This is very, *very* new, but for anyone reading this question in the future, there is a **space** method in VerticalGroup which is intended to allow you to define the spacing between elements:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/VerticalGroup.html#space(float)

You can find an example of it in action, here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/Scene2dTest.java

For those working with a slightly older version of libgdx, there is a **setSpacing** method that can be used instead.